# Allow eBay API IPs to access my server via Firewall on AWS whitelist

Tags: amazon-web-services, whitelist, ebay-api

I'm using the Amazon version of Linux. I need the eBay API to access image files hosted on this server, however I do not want this server open to the public. I'm trying to whitelist the eBay IPs.

This is what nslookup gives me:

```
Non-authoritative answer:
api.ebay.com    canonical name = api.g.ebay.com.
Name:   api.g.ebay.com
Address: 66.211.179.150
Name:   api.g.ebay.com
Address: 66.135.211.100
Name:   api.g.ebay.com
Address: 66.135.211.101
```

I added each one of these IP addresses to the AWS Security Group but it's still not working. It does work if I remove all restrictions from the firewall.

Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: You haven't indicated what errors you are getting. I assume ebay is hitting your server from another IP.

Comment: @tedder42 The API call I'm using is `UploadSiteHostedPictures` where I'm passing in the full URL of the image which is hosted on my server. The error is that it cannot access the URL. I know its because of the firewall as it works fine when I disable all restrictions.

Comment: If that's the case, there are other IPs hitting the firewall (presumably, your Security Group).